# Connect to a second database from wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to connect to my own self created second database using wordpress.
What i am trying to achieve is to extract data from my own database(not wordpress database) on my static wordpress front page.

I use php_everywhere plug in in order for me to write php code in blog post and pages.

I use the following code:

```
    <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "thomas";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "thomas";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * from number";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

However i got an error unexpected '"localhost"' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING).
Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

1) When using that plugin, be sure you've used straight quotes and backspace around the php to remove invisible control characters. And be sure the plugin doesn't have limitations on what it can do and ignores paragraph returns in the editor.

2) You're much better off using a page template in your theme and running PHP in a .php file and not in the post/page editor with a plugin. See [Page Templates | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/). Make a page template, add the calls to header, etc., and then work with your PHP in the file itself. Select the page template in the page editor of the page you're publishing in WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

You can create new object for new database connection and use that object to do any operation for external database

```
$mydb = new wpdb('thomas','password','thomas','localhost');
$rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from my_table");
```

You must have to use `$mydb` in place of `$wpdb`

Answer (score 0):

Wordpres provide a way to connect the other db.

```
     $mydb = new wpdb('thomas','password','thomas','localhost');
     $rows = $mydb->get_results("select Name from number");
     foreach ($rows as $row) :
        echo "id: " . $row->id. " - Name: " . $row->firstname. " " . $row->lastname. "<br>";
     endforeach;
```