# postgresql query inside WordPress dashboard

Tags: wordpress, postgresql

Am developing a website using WordPress with its bundled MySQL database. My organization stores all its data in PostgreSQL. I want to use certain fields from the PostgreSQL inside WordPress. I tried using PostgreSQL as second db but i cant fetch the details and not seeing any errors in log. I can find solutions to use MySQL second database but cant find one for PostgreSQL. It will be enlightening if someone provides a sample select query in PostgreSQL to use inside WordPress.

Comment: Looking into something similar. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50809951/460885 . You can create a secondary database connection using a a new wpdb object: `$mydb = new wpdb()....`

Answer (score 1):

WordPress is designed for MySQL or MariaDB, but not PostgreSQL.
That doesn't mean using PostgreSQL can't be used, but it does mean using it will be tricky and may cause more problems than it's worth.

SOLUTIONS:

**1. Use a plugin that allows PostgreSQL connections.**

https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/search/postgresql/

There aren't a lot and they don't seem well supported, but it may be worth a try.  Make back-ups etc. in case it doesn't work as planned.

**2. Copy data from PostgrSQL into MySQL**

This depends on the type of data you're importing and how often it needs updating.

Ex. If you want to import users from PostgreSQL into WordPress once a day.

I'd suggest setting up a script that pulls the data out of PostgreSQL and imports it into MySQL.

PHP can work. It would look something like:

1. Connect to PostgreSQL and query the data you need.
2. Get the results,
3. Connect to MySQL WordPress database
4. Run an import or update query to the appropriate tables.

If this needs to happen automatically on a regular basis, setting up a cron job is worthwhile.

Note:  You may be able to do this via an SQL query, but it may get tricky because you are connecting to 2 different types of databases.  A PHP script is a sure thing.

Comment: Thanks @lisa, i have found an external login plugin to do a one way authentication from postgresql to wordpress. However, i can't do any operations from wordpress to postgresql. The idea on import is interesting let me put my hands on it :)